# how to configure hot swap agent with liferay server

Tags: tomcat, jvm, liferay, hotswap, dcevm

I want to configure hotswap agent and DCEVM with liferay server.
I have added DCEVM in jdk and also added "**-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:D:\onkar\DCEVM\hotswap-agent.jar**" in setenv.bat file.
Now after deploying war file either server doesn't start properly or war file is not getting deployed properly.

Please help if anyone knows how to configure it with liferay server.

Answer (score 2):

With Hotswap Agent you can do java code changes and check those immediately without the need to restart the TOMCAT SERVER

Double Click on Server - Runtime Environment - JRE must be mapped to the same JRE of JDK in which DECVM is patched in step-1

[image]

Add “-XXaltjvm="dcevm" -javaagent:\HotswapAgent.jar” in VM Arguments

[image]

Run Tomcat on  SErver in Debug mode

With Liferay SERVER, HOT SWAP Agent starts, but I have a PERMGEN exception.

[Other info](http://tirthalpatel.blogspot.it/2014/06/steps-to-setup-hotswap-agent-in-eclipse.html)

Comment: The configuration which you said is correct for Tomcat but I need configuration for liferay server. Liferay internally uses tomcat server only but I am getting issues in starting server with the same configuration.

Comment: adding the file hotswap-agent.properties with this option setted "disabledPlugins=Seam" and setting this VM arguments :"-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=370m -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+EnableInvokeDynamic -XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:E:\java\hotswap-agent.jar" , the server starts and load the Java Project.